# How do I fix 'Error: PasteSpecial method of Range class failed'?

Tags: excel, vba, methods, copy-paste

I'm trying to write a macro that copies tables (colors, formats etc.) from the sheet for each day (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Friday) and pastes to sheets (262 sheets) for the same day. (Monday - Monday etc.) Sheets names I have in sheet "Data".

But I got this error:

> Run-time error '1004': Method PasteSpecial class Range Failure.

This is my VBA macro:

```
Sub copy_paste()

For i = 1 To 262
    If 1 = i Mod 5 Then
        Worksheets("wednesday").Activate
        Cells.Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        ' This is the problem part of code (said Debugger)
        Sheets(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2).Value).Range("A1").PasteSpecial _
            Paste:=x1PasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=x1None _
            , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
    If 2 = i Mod 5 Then
        Sheets("thursday").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2).Value).Range("A1").PasteSpecial _
            Paste:=x1PasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=x1None _
            , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
    If 3 = i Mod 5 Then
        Sheets("friday").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2).Value).Range("A1").PasteSpecial _
            Paste:=x1PasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=x1None _
            , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
    If 4 = i Mod 5 Then
        Sheets("monday").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2).Value).Range("A1").PasteSpecial _
            Paste:=x1PasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=x1None _
            , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
    If 0 = i Mod 5 Then
        Sheets("tuesday").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2).Value).Range("A1").PasteSpecial _
            Paste:=x1PasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=x1None _
            , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You're only selecting cells on Wednesday - on other days there is no "Cells.Select" call.

Comment: I corrected that, but I getting still the same Error.

Comment: You have `x1` everywhere in your code instead of `xl`.

Comment: Thank you, but after I corrected that, I getting still the same error ...

Comment: please check whether it should be `Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone` instead of `Operation:=x1None`

Comment: try explicitly referencing ThisWorkbook (or whatever workbook is actually used) in worksheet references, like `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")`, rather than implying the active workbook. It can cause problems as soon as another workbook is open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I fixed these two issues, it works.

> You have x1 everywhere in your code instead of xl.
> – Justyna MK

> please check whether it should be Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone instead of Operation:=x1None
> – skkakkar

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Worksheets("SheetName").Paste method, instead of the Range.PasteSpecial method.

But really, I'd recommend using a full up worksheet copy if you're literally copying everything:

```
    Worksheets("wednesday").Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 2).Value
```